# benefit of initialising an object using proxy method?

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, fastapi

I was going through fastapi source code and there I saw param_functions file.

```
def Path(  # noqa: N802
    default: Any = Undefined,
    *,
    alias: Optional[str] = None,
    title: Optional[str] = None,
    description: Optional[str] = None,
    gt: Optional[float] = None,
    ge: Optional[float] = None,
    lt: Optional[float] = None,
    le: Optional[float] = None,
    min_length: Optional[int] = None,
    max_length: Optional[int] = None,
    regex: Optional[str] = None,
    example: Any = Undefined,
    examples: Optional[Dict[str, Any]] = None,
    deprecated: Optional[bool] = None,
    include_in_schema: bool = True,
    **extra: Any,
) -> Any:
    return params.Path(
        default=default,
        alias=alias,
        title=title,
        description=description,
        gt=gt,
        ge=ge,
        lt=lt,
        le=le,
        min_length=min_length,
        max_length=max_length,
        regex=regex,
        example=example,
        examples=examples,
        deprecated=deprecated,
        include_in_schema=include_in_schema,
        **extra,
    )
```

Ultimately they are forwarding their calls to `Path` class initialiser. My question is
why are they doing it like this? and why not simply use the class instead of calling a method which calls the class initialiser, why not directly initialise the class.

Comment: In general for better typing and static analysis support: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/pull/226 - a class constructor can only return objects of that class (the result of a class being instantiated would be that class - not a string for example), while these dependencies (implemented as functions) can return whatever (`Any`). Not related: a method is a function that belongs to an object or class; if it's just a plain function like in this case it's named a function.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was trying to find out the reason but couldn't find any. could you help in how were you able to find it like what were your steps in getting answer of the question.

Comment: I read through the source of the file where the function is defined, looked at the commit history and moved to the referenced issue (as linked above) from the initial commit.